# Super slow Vimeo API video upload

Tags: .net, video, vimeo

Using the API to upload videos either HTTP or HTTPS is really slow. Same upload using Vimeo website is fast.

Specs for Test:
Clean imaged machine
17MB H.264 MP4 file that is in line with the approved specs of Vimeo’s guide lines.
Simple console application that uploads the video file to Vimeo using VimeoDotNet
Uploading through VimeoDotNet of the 17MB file:
•   8min mark with the progress at 65% the video shows up on Vimeo with the status of processing. 
•   28min mark and progress at 85% the video is now playable on Vimeo website.
•   40min mark progress has now hit 95%.
•   46min and 40 seconds hit 100% and completes successful.
Uploading through just Vimeo on their Website of the 17MB file:
•   Less then a minute to fully upload the file.
•   Less then a minute to full conversion of the file.

Comment: The VimeoDotNet library is not an official Vimeo library, and may have a slower upload implementation. Are you able to attempt the PHP, JS or Python upload libraries and see if they are any faster? In my experience the PHP library has been the fastest of the three because it can offload most of the work directly to curl.

Comment: Needs to be .NET, I could make all the calls using REST directly instead of  using VimeoDotNet but I would be doing pretty much the same thing. Performance using .NET with other sites like YouTube and Twitter have been fine.

Comment: Once Vimeo releases their own upload library, it should have speed parity with the rest of the libraries. It is on our roadmap but we do not have an estimate as to it's release.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the Automatic pull option rather than upload?
From the Vimeo page "This is the best (and easiest) approach if the video is already posted on the Internet, at a URL accessible by Vimeo's upload server."

https://developer.vimeo.com/api/upload/videos

Much much faster than uploading.
Just to expand on this. We run the video generation tool on a fast VPS, place the files in a seperate public folder(webserver). then call

```
var response = vc.Request("/me/videos", "POST", false, "type=pull&link=http://someserver.com/156755.mp4");
```

Vimeo will then respond with details for the video. At this point vimeo downloads the video from that url and sorted.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the issue was a default chunk size that was way too small, 10K. I changed it to 1Mb and now uploads are fast.